# How can I serve multiple React Native apps with Meteor on NGINX server?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor, nginx, react-native

I am trying to configure an NGINX server with multiple ports and proxy_pass parameters so my server can handle multiple Meteor/React Native apps. My RN app connects with

```
let METEOR_URL = 'ws://52.X.XXX.168/websocket';//<=or 168:80/websocket
Meteor.connect(METEOR_URL);
```

which works only if I don't specify a port or specify port 80. I'm deploying my app with

```
ROOT_URL=http://localhost PORT=3030 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/MyApp node /home/ubuntu/myapp/bundle/main.js
```

(but have also tried with ROOT_URL=http://localhost:8010 for example)
and this all works. But I'm running into trouble if I try to run a second app in any way. I've tried a multiple server upstream block in my nginx.conf, multiple server blocks with different listening ports, but I can never change the METEOR_URL in the RN app to a different port and have the RN app get any data (get error 'No subscription existing for 'mydata'').

My nginx.conf looks roughly like this, with things that I've tried commented out:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
# HTTP
#upstream app {
#    server 172.0.0.132:3030;
#    server 172.0.0.132:3060;
#}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    #listen 3030;
    #listen 3060;
    listen 3090;


    # pass requests to Meteor
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3030; # or 'app' if using upstream block

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; #for websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

  root /var/www/html;
  server_name localhost;
}

server {
  listen 3060;
server_name  MyApp;
# pass requests to Meteor
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; #for websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

}
```

Any suggestion as to how I should go about this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Phusion Passenger with nginx for Meteor, it's very easy to set up, and their tutorials/getting started is very good:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/

It will look after keeping meteor running, and can run everything on port 80/443 as required

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping not to go down that road, but maybe it would be best eventually...for now I guess I'll just set up different servers for each app, as clumsy as that seems. Frustrating, because I'm sure it must be do-able...

Comment: Doing it with Passenger is actually easy, and it's a permanent solution. There is a wizard in the documentation that leads you through the process. The config file for each server is very small and simple, you will wonder why you didn't do it in the first place, and its actually more work to set up separate servers